# Error when using powershell 7 foreach-object -parallel and AWS S3 module to download S3 folder content

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, powershell-7.0

I have the following basic AWS powershell script downloading all of the content of an S3 bucket folder.

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName $s3BucketName -keyPrefix $keyPrefix | Read-S3Object -Folder "C:\temp\Events\"
```

Unfortunately, it runs too slow as the folder contains hundreds of small files and I need to build in parallel downloads.

I've tried to use foreach-object -parallel using the following script

```
$S3object = Get-S3Object -BucketName $s3BucketName -keyPrefix $keyPrefix
$S3object | foreach-object -parallel { Read-S3Object -Key $_ -Folder "C:\temp\Events\" }
```

But get the following error

> [Error] ERROR: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.Exception             :Type              : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingExceptionMessage           : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.ErrorId           : AmbiguousParameterSetLine              : 1Offset            : 2CommandInvocation :MyCommand        : Read-S3ObjectBoundParameters  :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     :Length : 3Length : 6Values   :Length : 24Length : 25SyncRoot :Comparer : System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparerCount    : 2Keys     : …Values   : …SyncRoot : …ScriptLineNumber : 1OffsetInLine     : 2HistoryId        : 1Line             :  Read-S3Object -Key $_ -Folder "C:\temp\Events"PositionMessage  : At line:1 char:2+  Read-S3Object -Key $_ -Folder "C:\temp\Events"+

When I write-host the contents of $S3object I get this:

> INFORMATION: Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using another method such as a job, and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: You would get a very similar error if this was not PS Core, are you sure this is not Windows PowerShell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `-Parallel` script block, provide `$_` as input *via the pipeline*, analogous to what your first command does without parallelism:

```
$S3object | 
  ForEach-Object -Parallel { $_ | Read-S3Object -Folder "C:\temp\Events\" }
```

Alternatively, judging by [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Read-S3Object.html), you could have used `-S3Object` instead of `-Key`.

Answer (score 0):

As @mklement0 say you can manipulate the collection element piped inside the ForEach-Object using $_ and any property of it ($_.Name) for exemple.

But for using other variables that are outside the ForEach-Object you need to use your variable like this : **$using:variable.**

Someting like :

```
$S3object = Get-S3Object -BucketName $s3BucketName -keyPrefix $keyPrefix
$S3object | foreach-object -parallel {
Write-output('KeyPrefix used : ' + $using:keyPrefix)

Read-S3Object -Key $_ -Folder "C:\temp\Events\" 
} -ThrottleLimit 4
```

`